# read line and remove newline character using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have shell script which generate sql queries based on a values in text file. My text file 
has values as follows (line by line)
[image]

my shell script is this.

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME="tableNames.txt"
COLUMNA="ca"
COLUMNB="cb"
cat $NAME | while read LINE

do
echo "CREATE TABLE \"$LINE\" (
        forward_speed double precision,
    backward_speed double precision
      );"
done
```

LINE variable get the value from textfile correctly but it has newline character how do i remove new line character.

Comment: Comes the file `tableNames.txt` from a non-linux system ?

Comment: no it's in Linux system, the image was taken from windows system thats' all.

Comment: This is not the behaviour of `read ` so your file probably contains an extra "newline". What gives `cat -v tableNames.txt ` ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably generated the text file on a windows machine or some other setting with dos line endings.  You can fix that by either

- converting the file to unix line endings with dos2unix
- deleting '\r' characters: `cat $FILE | tr -d '\r' | while read LINE ...`
- use a utility like awk to grab the first field: `cat $FILE | awk '{print $1}' | while read LINE ...`

Comment: you could improve a little second example : `tr -d '\r' <"$FILE" | while read LINE ...`

Answer (score 2):

If `tabeNames.txt` is from Windows you should do a [dos2unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) filter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem working with output from a Busybox docker container on Fedora.

I was using the output from docker run to do further processing, but could'nt get it to work for multiple hours.

I solved my problem by piping the output to a file

```
...
res=$(docker run -it ....)
echo $res > tmp.txt
dos2unix tmp.txt
cat tmp.txt | while read line;
do
...
```

Hope this helps others solve similar issues with container output

Answer (score 0):

A quick & dirty to way to account for all cases is to add a "junk" variable to the end of the read command.  If there's a <cr> hiding at the end of the line, it'll be stored in the junk variable rather than at the end of the variable before it; if not, the junk variable will just end up being set to an empty string.

Example:

```
read a b c xx < file.txt
```

will read values from 3 space-delimited columns from a file of uncertain origin with no risk of appending a <cr> to the 3rd variable.